# Firebase Dynamic Links doesn't navigate to deep link on iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-dynamic-links

Using **Firebase Dynamic Links** in a **Managed Workflow Expo** app directs to the correct deep link in the app on Android, but on iOS only opens the app in either whatever page was last open or the homepage.

app.config.js

```
ios: {
    associatedDomains: [
      'applinks:*.myapp.web.app',
      'applinks:myapp.web.app',
      'applinks:*.myapp.page.link',
      'applinks:myapp.page.link',
    ],
},
```

AppNavigation.js

```
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [
      prefix,
      'https://myapp.web.app',
      'https://*.myapp.web.app',
    ],
```

The apple-app-site-association file stored on myapp.web.app

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "1234567890.com.my.app",
                "paths": [ "*" ]
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

The Dynamic Link is generated using REST API with the following payload:

```
    const payload = {
      dynamicLinkInfo: {
        domainUriPrefix: 'https://myapp.page.link',
        link: `https://myapp.web.app/${deepLink}`,
        androidInfo: {
          androidPackageName: com.my.app,
        },
        iosInfo: {
          iosBundleId: com.my.app,
          iosAppStoreId: 1234567890,
        },
```

The generated Dynamic Link opens the app and directs to the `${deepLink}` on Android as expected, but not on iOS. This was tested in an app built with EAS built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up solving this myself. Dynamic Links get resolved (converted from short link to full link) automatically on Android, but on iOS this has to be done manually with `dynamicLinks().resolveLink(url);`

After resolving, the link gets picked up by React Native Navigation and works like a normal deep link.

Full code for Dynamic Links:

```
  const linking = {
    prefixes: [
      'https://myapp.page.link',
      'https://myapp.web.app',
    ],

    async getInitialURL() {
      // If the app was opened with a Firebase Dynamic Link
      const dynamicLink = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink();
      if (dynamicLink) {
        const { url } = dynamicLink;
        const resolvedLink = await dynamicLinks().resolveLink(url);
        return resolvedLink.url;
      }

      // If the app was opened with any other link (sometimes the Dynamic Link also ends up here, so it needs to be resolved
      const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
      if (initialUrl) {
        const resolvedLink = await dynamicLinks().resolveLink(initialUrl);
        return (resolvedLink) ? resolvedLink.url : initialUrl;
      }
    },

    subscribe(listener) {
      const handleDynamicLink = (dynamicLink) => {
        listener(dynamicLink.url);
      };

      // Listen to incoming links from deep linking
      const unsubscribeToDynamicLinks = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);

      return () => {
        // Clean up the event listeners
        unsubscribeToDynamicLinks();
      };
    },
  };
```

In my case I also had to install all 3 of the following libraries:

```
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "16.4.3",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "16.4.3",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "16.4.3",
```